# Can't find custom controller class in custom class dropdown Xcode 8.3.2

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3, xcode8

I just started developing for iOS and WatchOS and have encountered a small issue that is probably very simple but I can't find any solution for it.

The issue I'm having is that I'm trying to structure my files in my own way but when creating new controllers, I cannot find them in the `Custom Class` dropdown on the `Interface.storyboard`

[image]

For example, I renamed `InterfaceController.swift` to `Controllers/InitialViewController.swift` to better match what I'm trying to do with my project structure.

[image]

For some reason InterfaceController still is showing up on there and if I type in the fullname of the new class, it won't show up. I'm unable to get that class here.

Any help at all would be great, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Renaming your file will not change the class name. You will have to modify the class declaration inside the file.

```
class InitialViewController: UIViewController {
    /* code for your class */
}
```

Also, putting your files inside folders (blue folder icon) or Xcode groups (yellow folder icon) will not affect the class name.

Comment: Wow... it's one of those days. I can't believe I missed something so simple. Is one way better than another, groups vs folders?

Comment: @JoeScotto Groups vs. folders: Groups are a way for Xcode to show you an organized tree, even if all your files are in the same folder. If you add a folder to your source tree, Xcode will try to automatically track all files you may add to it. Future versions of Xcode may try to offer better interoperability between the two concepts, since it's a bit messy at the moment. Sticking with groups for now may be the easiest.